# Compiling a class which depends on jena

Tags: java, maven, jena

I've written some code that manipulates RDF, and so is dependent on the [jena framework](http://jena.apache.org/).  I'm trying to compile / package it using maven.  The compilation completes, but when I try and run the generated jar file, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at my.package.name.ClassName.<clinit>(SchemaAPI.java:96)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jena.tdb.sys.EnvTDB.processGlobalSystemProperties(EnvTDB.java:33)
    at org.apache.jena.tdb.TDB.init(TDB.java:250)
    at org.apache.jena.tdb.sys.InitTDB.start(InitTDB.java:29)
    at org.apache.jena.system.JenaSystem.lambda$init$40(JenaSystem.java:114)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.apache.jena.system.JenaSystem.forEach(JenaSystem.java:179)
    at org.apache.jena.system.JenaSystem.forEach(JenaSystem.java:156)
    at org.apache.jena.system.JenaSystem.init(JenaSystem.java:111)
    at org.apache.jena.
```

This has been discussed before (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755846/jena-tdb-java-lang-exceptionininitializererror) and [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201602.mbox/%3C56B47B8A.2040407@apache.org%3E)) but I have modified my pom file to include the shade plugin - and this hasn't solved the issue, and I've hit a bit of a brickwall...

Based on the comments in the discussions in the links above I have checked my `META-INF/services/org.apache.jena.system.JenaSubsystemLifecycle` file in my `my-project-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar` file and it does indeed contain the reference to TDB (`org.apache.jena.tdb.sys.InitTDB`) - so I know that this is (almost certainly) the cause of the issue but I'm no nearer to finding a solution...

I'm also including the `maven-dependency-plugin` and the `maven-compiler-plugin` - I assume these won't be causing any conflict?

**Further info**

Some extra info in response to Andy S's comment.  The relevant part of my pom file is:

```
<transformers>
  <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
    <mainClass>uk.co.domain.mypackage.MyClass</mainClass>
  </transformer>
  <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
  <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ApacheLicenseResourceTransformer" />
  <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ApacheNoticeResourceTransformer">
    <addHeader>false</addHeader>
  </transformer>
</transformers>
```

The relevant file in `META-INF` only contains one class:

```
$more META-INF/services/org.apache.jena.system.JenaSubsystemLifecycle
org.apache.jena.tdb.sys.InitTDB
$
```

I've also tried adding

```
JenaSystem.init();
```

at the beginning of my main class, but this hasn't helped

Comment: do you have a github repo or something where you have the code you're trying to run?

Comment: Why don't you use a given version from maven central instead of building it?

Comment: @Ulises no, sorry (company policy about not releasing any code... :/ ) - I could try and make a (relatively) minimal example but wanted to check first there wasn't likely to be an obvious mistake I'm making

Comment: @NicolasFilotto sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: Why don't you use jena 3.1.0 for example from maven central instead of building from source (or I misunderstood your question)

Comment: @NicolasFilotto ah, I'm not building it from source :)

Comment: This is symptomatic of not packing the ServicLoader files correctly.  There are several, not one.  e.g. for shading, use  <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />  Check the contents of META-INF/services/org.apache.jena.system.JenaSubsystemLifecycle.

Does `META-INF/services/org.apache.jena.system.JenaSubsystemLifecycle` only have the TDB initializer? Theer shoudl be at least 4 classes there.

Comment: @AndyS I've added some more info

Comment: The META-INF/services/org.apache.jena.system.JenaSubsystemLifecycle is wrong. Are you using the shade plugin?  That what <transformers? is for.  See the jena-fuseki-server POM.

Comment: @AndyS yes I'm using the Shade plugin - I *think* I'm using it correctly (I've never used it before...). Is there anything wrong with the part of the pom file that I've put in the question? Where do I find the jena-fuseki-server pom? I've looked through the maven and epimorphics repositories but can't see it in either of them

Comment: @AndyS ok, I've found the jena-fuseki-server pom.  The _only_ thing that is different between the shade plugin configuration between that one and mine is the value of `<mainClass>` - should that stay as `org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd` or as the entry point for _my_ application (i.e. the value which I've got shown in my question)?

Comment: @ChrisW - the fragment looks OK - ServicesResourceTransformer is the one that matter here.  This is all quiet senstive to the dependencies as well.

Comment: @AndyS how do I find out what the dependencies are?

Comment: @AndyS according to the list at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-shade-plugin/2.4.3 I've got a copy of all of the dependencies in my .m2 folder

Comment: To find dependencies: `mvn dependency:tree`

Answer (score 1):

It's not a classpath issue, it's either a misuse or a misconfiguration issue. Basically, you get a null pointer exception [at line 33 of `EnvTDB`](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-tdb/src/main/java/org/apache/jena/tdb/sys/EnvTDB.java#L33), specifically `TDB.getContext()` returns `null`. Maybe try running this first:

```
org.apache.jena.query.ARQ.init();
```

Comment: Try debugging it, find out where it fails.

Comment: The error is the same as in my original question - I'm not really sure how to even start debugging it given it's to do with how maven packages external jars

Comment: I had a similar issue when running some code I wrote using Jena and the ARQ module (nothing to do with TDB though), the getContext() was returning a null pointer, but only when build as a `jar`. Running `org.apache.jena.query.ARQ.init();` solve the issue but I don't really understand why it's only happening when using the `jar` file.