# Creating executable JAR for Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, jar, jena

I was following this answer to [create an executable JAR using Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574650/4062881). However, I came up with the following error:

```
> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at me.vijaychavda.rdfr.Reifier.do_reify(Reifier.java:82)
    at me.vijaychavda.rdfr.Reifier.reify(Reifier.java:63)
    at me.vijaychavda.rdfr.Reifier.reify(Reifier.java:73)
    at me.vijaychavda.rdfr.Main.main(Main.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jena.tdb.sys.EnvTDB.processGlobalSystemProperties(EnvTDB.java:33)
    at org.apache.jena.tdb.TDB.init(TDB.java:249)
    at org.apache.jena.tdb.sys.InitTDB.start(InitTDB.java:29)
    at org.apache.jena.system.JenaSystem.lambda$init$2(JenaSystem.java:119)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1255)
    at org.apache.jena.system.JenaSystem.forEach(JenaSystem.java:194)
    at org.apache.jena.system.JenaSystem.forEach(JenaSystem.java:171)
    at org.apache.jena.system.JenaSystem.init(JenaSystem.java:117)
    at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.<clinit>(ModelFactory.java:49)
    ... 4 more
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12458509/4062881) answer helped me to get rid of `SLF4J` error, but after adding the dependency, I still get this error:

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at me.vijaychavda.rdfr.Reifier.do_reify(Reifier.java:82)
    at me.vijaychavda.rdfr.Reifier.reify(Reifier.java:63)
    at me.vijaychavda.rdfr.Reifier.reify(Reifier.java:73)
    at me.vijaychavda.rdfr.Main.main(Main.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jena.tdb.sys.EnvTDB.processGlobalSystemProperties(EnvTDB.java:33)
    at org.apache.jena.tdb.TDB.init(TDB.java:249)
    at org.apache.jena.tdb.sys.InitTDB.start(InitTDB.java:29)
    at org.apache.jena.system.JenaSystem.lambda$init$2(JenaSystem.java:119)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1255)
    at org.apache.jena.system.JenaSystem.forEach(JenaSystem.java:194)
    at org.apache.jena.system.JenaSystem.forEach(JenaSystem.java:171)
    at org.apache.jena.system.JenaSystem.init(JenaSystem.java:117)
    at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.<clinit>(ModelFactory.java:49)
    ... 4 more
```

My project is using Apache's Jena library.

Actually I'm new to Maven, and I just want to create executable JAR for my Java project :)

EDIT 1:

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36769519/4062881) and [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39089418/4062881) of using the Shade plugin, but same error!

EDIT 2:
The code runs fine without any errors. These errors come when I try to create the JAR.

Comment: Please paste **all** relevant files -- start with me.vijaychavda.rdfr.Reifier -- in their entirety

Comment: @hd1 The code runs fine, the error occurs only when I am building the JARs. I don't think code is problematic. There is something wrong I am doing about building a JAR using Maven

Comment: Can you please all the code in the `do_reify()` method in me.vijaychavda.rdfr.Reifier class?

Comment: @VijayChavda just humour me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not shaded all the service loader files into your combined jar:

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/jena-repack.html

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/system-initialization.html